# PCF cfdev plugin install No Such Host Error

Tags: devops, cloud-foundry, concourse, pcfdev

I tried to install Cloud Foundary `cfdev` plugin to setup pivotal cloud environment in local machine (MacOS Big Sur).

```
 ~ % cf install-plugin -r CF-Community cfdev
Searching CF-Community for plugin cfdev...
Plugin cfdev 0.0.18 found in: CF-Community
Attention: Plugins are binaries written by potentially untrusted authors.
Install and use plugins at your own risk.
Do you want to install the plugin cfdev? [yN]: y
Starting download of plugin binary from repository CF-Community...
Get https://d3p1cc0zb2wjno.cloudfront.net/cfdev/cfdev-v0.0.18-rc.36-darwin: dial tcp: lookup d3p1cc0zb2wjno.cloudfront.net: no such host
FAILED
```

Looks like unable to reach `d3p1cc0zb2wjno.cloudfront.net` host and even I tried hitting `https://d3p1cc0zb2wjno.cloudfront.net/cfdev/cfdev-v0.0.18-rc.36-darwin` endpoint in browser but no luck.

Any suggestion to try out, or resolution please?

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 3):

The link is simple broken. I was building the cfdev plugin with the generate-plugin.sh script in scripts folder. But be careful you need a go version 1.16.xx 1.17.xx is not working due to an bug on macos!

After building the plugin locally you can install the plugin with

```
cf install-plugin cfdev
```

The next problem you will get is that the certificates from bosh/director are expired and cfdev will not start :( I'm still searching for a solution for this.

Comment: Thanks, I had also tried using generate-plugin.sh but as you said the problem was go version 1.17.xx now it works. Now I also get x509: certificate has expired or is not yet valid when deploying bosh director, so please let me know if you can find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround by adjusting the time on the host machine for 01.2021 - in theory, could be any date less than 10.04.2021. I managed to get the full installation + apps-manager and scs. After that, the auto-sync of time could be restored.